# Help with an Incomplete Gamma function-like integral $\int_x^\infty t^{m-1}e^{-0.5 t^2 \pm pt} dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I was working on some mathematical derivations where I was struck with integrals of the form given below:

$$\int_x^\infty t^{m-1}e^{-0.5 t^2 \pm pt} dt$$

The integral seems very close to the incomplete gamma function integral. Note here that m and p are positive real numbers. I tried different forms of substitutions but none did work for me.

Any helpful notes, hints, references will be very much appreciated.

Comment: hint differentiate $\int_x^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2\pm pt}$ w.r.t.to $p$. then use the error function

Comment: Can you please show me the steps as I am a little bit lost?

Comment: complete the square, then use defintion of error function

Comment: Completing the square, the integrand will be in the form t^(m-1)*Exp[-0.5*(t+D)] where D is constant. How can I relate this to the error function? if m was an integer, I would have used the binomial theorem and the integral will be the incomplete gamma function. Can you please show me the steps?

Comment: $$
\int_x^{\infty}t^{m}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}\pm pt}dt=(\pm)^{m}\frac{d^{m}}{dp^{m}}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}\pm pt}dt
$$

can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, given that "m" is a real positive number (and may not be an integer), how can the fractional derivative for this error function be obtained analytically? Thank you.

Comment: @kazekage, I doubt tired's approach would work for general $m$. Are you sure all of your parameters are so general (what about $x$ by the way, you didn't say anything?)

Comment: @You're In My Eye , x, m and p are positive real numbers. I have checked multiple table-of-integrals books and software (e.g. Matlab and Mathematica) but could not find a direct solution. Taylor series could be used, but that would give me a series solution, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @kazekage, I don't see how Taylor series could be used here. Note, that you have the infinity as a limit, so integrating term by term is tricky

Comment: @You'reInMyEye Re Taylor series, note that $$\int_x^\infty t^{m-1}e^{-t^2/2 +qt} dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{q^k}{k!}\int_x^\infty t^{m+k-1}e^{-t^2/2}dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{q^k}{k!}\int_{x^2/2}^\infty 2^{(m+k)/2-1} s^{(m+k)/2-1}e^{-s}ds$$ which is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{q^k}{k!}2^{(m+k)/2-1}\Gamma\left(\tfrac12(m+k),\tfrac12x^2\right).$$

Comment: @Did, ah, Taylor series in $p$. Yes, of course, this series is possible

Comment: Yes, by "tayloring" the Exp[+/-p*t], you can get a infinite series solution with the aid of incomplete gamma function. I also though of using the Mejier-G or Fox H-Function to represent this integral, but they are computationally expensive and I am seeking a simpler solution (if any).